# System Verilog- How to ensure that specific code will be executed before another?

Tags: system-verilog

I have the following code in my monitor:

```
virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
      fork
     begin : clock_c
        forever begin
           wait(vif.fact_log2_samp != fact_log2_samp_init);
           for(int counter = 0; counter < 46; counter++) begin
          check = 1'b0;
          @(posedge vif.clk);
           end
          **check =1'b1;**
        end// forever
     end// clock_c 
     begin : main_0
        forever begin
           mon_trx = tx_lin_int_transaction::type_id::create("mon_trx");
           mon_trx.fact_log_2 = fact_log2_samp_init;           
           **wait (vif.xn_valid == 1'b1);**
           #1;   
           mon_trx.rand_data_xi = vif.xi;
           mon_trx.rand_data_xq = vif.xq;
           if (check == 1'b0)
         mon_trx.check = FALSE;
           else
          fact_log2_samp_init = vif.fact_log2_samp;
           $cast(t, mon_trx.clone());
           //send transaction to scoreboard via TLM write()
           ap.write(t);
           wait (vif.xn_valid == 1'b0);
        end// forever
     end// main_0
      join
   endtask: run_phase
```

The problem is that

```
wait(vif.xn_valid == 1'b1);
```

and the code after it execute just before

```
check =1'b1;
```

(same time).
How can I ensure that the

```
check =1'b1;
```

will execute before?

Comment: Use an [event](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/uvm/what-difference-between-event-and-wait-event.triggered) (may be edge or level triggered depending on the requirement). Trigger event in `clock_c`, just after `check =1'b1;` and wait in `main_0` thread.

Comment: @sharvil111 -  can you demonsrate how?

Comment: Something similar to [this](http://www.verificationguide.com/p/systemverilog-events.html). With some logic modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow the named events method, as AndresM suggested, but if you need a quick sync in the very same block with the very same trigger condition, a simple `#0` might solve the issue, thou it is unreliable due to the simulation time handling reasons. Might worth a try:

```
begin : clock_c
  ...
    **check =1'b1;**
  ...
end
begin : main_0
  ...
  #0;
  **wait (vif.xn_valid == 1'b1);**
  ...
end
```

also you can use labels for the begin-end blocks to look and read better, eg.:
`begin: main_0`, `end: main_0` instead of `end // main_o`

Comment: Please check @dave_59's reply on this other [thread](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/question-about-0).  Even though #0 might in some cases work, it is just a hack.  You'd be better off if you learn to use the constructs that the language provides for this.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Chapter 15 of the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), where they cover in great detail every aspect related to the different interprocess synchronization and communication mechanisms that the SystemVerilog language offers.  Those options are listed below (follow the hyperlinks to see a few examples and how to use each one of them):

1. [Semaphores](http://www.testbench.in/SV_29_SEMAPHORE.html)
2. [Mailboxes](http://www.testbench.in/SV_30_MAILBOX.html)
3. [Named Events](http://www.testbench.in/SV_22_EVENTS.html)